# How to use sql Array with Sybase database?

Tags: jdbc

I'm getting `"createArrayOf(String arg0, Object[] arg1)has not been completed and should not be called."` run time exception while using **sql** Array with **Sybase** database.

Usage:

```cs
String[] list = {"test"};
statement.setArray(1, statement.getConnection().createArrayOf("varchar", ist));
```

Exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.sybase.jdbc4.utils.UnimplementedOperationException: The method com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybConnection.public Array createArrayOf(String arg0, Object[] arg1) has not been completed and should not be called.
    at com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.ErrorMessage.raiseRuntimeException(Unknown Source)
    at com.sybase.jdbc4.utils.Debug.notImplemented(Unknown Source)
    at com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybConnection.createArrayOf(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: The error clearly states that the method isn't implemented, so most likely the driver simply doesn't support SQL ARRAYs

Comment: Yes, do I need to use some other driver? Presently I'm using jconn4.jar. I also tried Jconnect 7, but it has same problem.

Comment: You need to check that with Sybase (or the documentation of the driver).